# Get data from an object using string format

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

Is there a way to get object data using string format.
For example I have data format like.

```
{
    "id": "3eef1",
    "name": "Admin",
    "email": "email@example.com",
    "primary_role": {
        "id": "a37ad",
        "name": "Shani",
        "description": " Users",
        "created_at": 1652413392,
        "updated_at": 1652413392
    },
    "created_at": 1652413392,
    "updated_at": 1652413392,
    "roles": [],
    "profile": null,
    "companies": []
}
]
```

How can I get `primary_role` in the form of string
Like I am doing `'primary_role'.name` which is of course a wrong approach.

I have to use it in string format. no loops or looped functions.

Comment: `array[idx].primary_role.name`

Answer (score 0):

Use npm module [jsonpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONPath) to get the list for name:

```
const jp = require("jsonpath")
let source = [{
  "id": "3eef1",
  "name": "Admin",
  "email": "email@example.com",
  "primary_role": {
      "id": "a37ad",
      "name": "Shani",
      "description": " Users",
      "created_at": 1652413392,
      "updated_at": 1652413392
  },
  "created_at": 1652413392,
  "updated_at": 1652413392,
  "roles": [],
  "profile": null,
  "companies": []
}]
let result = jp.query(source, "$[0].primary_role.name")
console.log(result)

// or update your source be a json object
source = {
  "id": "3eef1",
  "name": "Admin",
  "email": "email@example.com",
  "primary_role": {
      "id": "a37ad",
      "name": "Shani",
      "description": " Users",
      "created_at": 1652413392,
      "updated_at": 1652413392
  },
  "created_at": 1652413392,
  "updated_at": 1652413392,
  "roles": [],
  "profile": null,
  "companies": []
}
console.log(source.primary_role.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to store the object in a variable to access it.

```js
const obj = {
    "id": "3eef1",
    "name": "Admin",
    "email": "email@example.com",
    "primary_role": {
        "id": "a37ad",
        "name": "Shani",
        "description": " Users",
        "created_at": 1652413392,
        "updated_at": 1652413392
    },
    "created_at": 1652413392,
    "updated_at": 1652413392,
    "roles": [],
    "profile": null,
    "companies": []
};
```

Then you can call any of its properties using [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics#dot_notation) like this:

```js
console.log(obj.primary_role.name);
```